# Display percentage symbol in column A using Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet query result which I need to display with the % for A column

[image]

The expected result is

[image]

I have the query result formula as

```
=arrayformula({{"MWST ",""}} & QUERY(query(BuchungSystem!A2:AZ,"Select M, N, L where Q = "& $B$10),"SELECT Col1*100, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1, Col3 LABEL SUM(Col2) '' , Col1*100 ''"))
```

I cannot use custom number format menu since this ranges is to be combined with other ranges in above cells using {;}

Comment: Can you give us a better example of what you're going to combine? Is it just a concatenation/joining of two cell strings? Will you do any arithmetic operations with the numeric values? Also, if you could provide a copy or an exemple sheet, it would help  a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `&{"%",""}` before the closing arrayformula bracket.

`=arrayformula({{"MWST ",""}} & QUERY(query(BuchungSystem!A2:AZ,"Select M, N, L where Q = "& $B$10),"SELECT Col1*100, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1, Col3 LABEL SUM(Col2) '' , Col1*100 ''")&{"%",""})`